# "Take account of" vs. "take into account"

Tags: meaning, differences

Is there any difference in meaning between:

> 1. take account of
> 2. take into account

Or do they both mean "to take into consideration"?

Answer (score 2):

*Take account of* means to pay attention to someone or something, take notice of, *as well as to take into consideration.

*take into account* means to take into consideration.

They're so close as to be fairly interchangeable, take into account usually allows a sentence to flow more smoothly.

Comment: Yes, but syntactically you can only *take account of **X***, whereas you can *take **X** into account* or *take into account **X*** according to your preference and the "flow" of your intended context. That's not necessarily the only (or even a significant) factor in overall preference, but [latterly, OP's format #2 is much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=taken+that+into+account%2Ctaken+account+of+that&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctaken%20that%20into%20account%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctaken%20account%20of%20that%3B%2Cc0)...

Comment: ...my advice to OP would be *don't bother trying to use #1 at all - just be aware other people still do sometimes.*

Comment: I was going to post a comment to you earlier today, to ask if you would consider signing up for ELL - I didn't, obviously, since I discovered you'd already done this a few days before. To my mind, this current question (and many, many more) are a bit pointless on ELU (I mean, c'mon - is it really likely to be of interest to [linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts?](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) Anyway, you're obviously going down well here, but I bet you'll soon become even more valued on ELL (you did say you were once a *teacher*, after all! :)